# currently using eclipse, not able to get out of debug mode

Tags: java, android, eclipse

whenever I run my android app, the debug window pops up, and freezes on some thread, then the "no source found" error pops up. I dont want to see this. I just want to see the error message. It use to do this until i accidentily hit some button.

I have tried to run the app in "resource" tab, I right clicked on my project--> run as --> android application, yet I can not get it out of this debug mode.

I hit that red disconnect button, yet same problem.

Comment: Try restarting the device & eclipse!

Answer (score 5):

Well you should see the Exception in the LogCat window. As far as the environment switching to debug mode, you should see a few buttons in the very top right corner to switch between "Java" and "Debug" as well ass sometimes "DDMS" if you use it.

If you cant find those options try Ctrl + F8 to switch to the next perspective.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

It is a perspective,btw.
To go to normal persperctive, Select Window from the toolbar, Window->Open Perspective->Select Java(Default)